# Bash: Both date "%b" and date "%h" (and of course) date "%B" gives full name of month?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu-12.04

I am writing a shell-script in Ubuntu server 12.04 which is supposed to compare some data in a log file.
In the log file, the date is given in the format:

```
[Mon Apr 08 15:02:54 2013]
```

As you can see, it states **Apr**.

According to the [man-page](http://ss64.com/bash/date.html), the option to be used in bash for this is **b** or **h**.

However it doesn't matter wether I (in my comparing script, or directly in shell) use **b**, **h** or **B**. They all return the full name of the month.

```
date +"%b" #Returns april (should have returned Apr)
date +"%h" #Returns april (should have returned Apr)
date +"%B" #Returns april (correct? Should it not be capital A?)
```

This of course makes it very difficult to do comparisons based on the date...

Has anyone else experienced this, and found a solution?

(I'm not sure if this is relevant, but I chose Norwegian as installation language when I installed the server.)

Thank's to the answer of @toro2k here, I ended up with a working solution:

```
DATE=`LC_ALL=C date +%b" "%d" "%H`
```

(This did not work:

```
LC_ALL=C
```

DATE=`date +%b" "%d" "%H`

)

Comment: redHat install for US/UK gives date +"%b" -> Apr. Good catch on your part re: installed for Norwegian. Maybe setting LC* envvars can fix it? (Search here, you'll find examples and discussions). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter You were right about that. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've tested it and the problem seems to be the norwegian localization:

```
$ LC_ALL=C date +%b
Apr

$ LC_ALL=nn_NO.UTF-8 date +%b
april
```

therefore when you try to parse the log file you should set the `LC_ALL` environment variable to `C`, i.e.

```
LC_ALL=C command
```

or

```
export LC_ALL=C
# your script code here
export -n LC_ALL
```

For more informations on locales setting see the [Locale](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale) page on Ubuntu wiki.